# In a Spring-XD job module, how to write data to two files respectively at the same path in two servers where XD containers are running?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

My XD cluster has two node servers, so there're two XDadmins and two XDcontainers. When I launch the job in XD-shell through one Admin server, the job writes data to the file at one node. At the other node, no data is written.
I want the job to write data to these two servers under the installation directory, such as /app/spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE/xd/files/.
In the job, I use `java.util.Properties class` to write data to files.

```
// file is the path where I want to put the file
properties.store(new FileOutputStream(file), "update properties");
```

My job is like
`job create --name Generate_properties_to_file --definition "GenProperties --proFile=/app/spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE/xd/files/test.properties --otherparameters=''" --deploy`

How could I modify the job module to implement the function?

Comment: With your setup where everything is duplicated on each node and you run the job on one of them, I'm not surprised to hear data is written only in that node. The job will not write data to both nodes until you tell it to do so, do you agree? BTW, Spring XD is deprecated in favor of [Spring Cloud DataFlow](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/).

Comment: How to tell Spring-XD to write data to both nodes? Sometimes it writes data to node1, and sometimes writes data to node2. It seems SpringXd picks one of the XDcontainers at random to handle the job and write the data where the XDcontainer is.